# How to create chained methods in Java

Tags: java, fluent

I have a class responsible for controlling the objects created during runtime - it builds them from inputs at swing frames - just as a DAO. It has this method that removes already created objects:

```
public void removeFrom(Class<?> clazz, int index) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : modelsMap.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().equals(clazz.getSimpleName())) {
            ((ArrayList<Object>) entry.getValue()).remove(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of calling this method and passing the referent class and index, I'd like the method call to be like this: `dao.removeFrom(MyObject.class).at(myIndex);` Guess it's looks like chained methods as the Stream API uses. Glad if anyone can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case your `removeFrom()` method should return wrapper around `((ArrayList<Object>) entry.getValue())`. And that wrapper has to have method `at(int index)` which removes element for given index.

And you also need to think about corner case when your `modelsMap` doesn't have entry for a given `clazz`.

Comment: With wrapper you mean a class that 'holds it', isn't it?

Comment: @AndréSpironello, yes, class which will store that list as an inner property.

Answer (score 0):

Please check on the Builder design pattern. Try creating builder design pattern for a simple object which has few attributes and getters and setters.

Once you are able to do that, method chaining will look very clear. :)

Comment: Yeah, I even considered using something like a builder pattern, but this method should be void, that is, doesn't have to create any object

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a DaoRemover class that you can instantiate by a factory method and which the instance methods return the current instance.

For example :

```
public class DaoRemover {
    private Map<String, Object> modelsMap; // your actual data
    private final List<ArrayList<Object>> list; // list of list after filtering on the class


    public static DaoRemover of(Class<?> clazz) {
        return new DaoRemover(clazz);
    }

    private DaoRemover(Class<?> clazz) {
        list = modelsMap.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getKey()
                                      .equals(clazz.getSimpleName()))
                        .map(e -> (ArrayList<Object>) e.getValue())
                        .collect(toList());
    }

    public DaoRemover at(int index) {
        list.forEach(l -> l.remove(index));
        return this;
    }

}
```

You could do now :

```
DaoRemover.of(MyObject.class)
          .at(myIndex);
```

or

```
DaoRemover.of(MyObject.class)
          .at(myIndex) 
          .at(myOtherIndex);
```